# HTMLAgilityPack & C#, How to display Extracted values from HTML into TextBox - WinForms

Tags: c#, html, dom, html-agility-pack

I want to display this value into textBox1 (WinForms), only one value no need for loop here.

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\detial.html");
        var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//Div[@for='city']").InnerText;
        textBox1 = var.ToString(); // I got error here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that tbx_city is a `TextBox` control,  then you would need to assign the value to `tbx_City.Text = var.ToString();`.

I would also recommend you improve your question by specifying the error message you are getting.